# How do I reshape my data so that IDs with multiple observations are grouped as all possible pairs of observations by ID?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transformation

Given a data frame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2], 'letter':['a','b','c','b','d'], 'value':[0,0,0,1,1]})

       id   let val
    0   1   a   0
    1   1   b   0
    2   1   c   0
    3   2   b   1
    4   2   d   1
```

I want to generate a version where the 'letter' column is all possible pairs by id. Order doesn't matter (b,d) is the same as (d,b). The pairs don't necessarily need to be represented using tuples either.

```
pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2], 'letter':[('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','c'),('b','d')], 'value':[0,0,0,1]})

    id  let     val
0   1   (a, b)  0
1   1   (a, c)  0
2   1   (b, c)  0
3   2   (b, d)  1
```

How can I transform my data to the desired output? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) as a [`combination`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
from itertools import combinations

out = (df.groupby('id', as_index=False)
         .agg({'letter': lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)),
               'value': 'first'})
         .explode('letter')
      )
```

Output:

```
   id  letter  value
0   1  (a, b)      0
0   1  (a, c)      0
0   1  (b, c)      0
1   2  (b, d)      1
```